# Shorthand for overloading multiple functions

Tags: c++, overloading

Assuming I have code such as the one below:

```
bool isString(char* arg) { return true; }
bool isString(const char* arg) { return true; }
bool isString(std::string arg) { return true; }

// Any other type...
template <typename type> bool isString(type arg) { return false; }
```

The question is, does C++ allow for any plausible way to shorten the syntax below to something similar to the concept below (syntactic shorthand/ sugar):

```
// Could be `char*`, `const char*` or `std::string` here.
bool isString([char*, const char*, std::string] arg) { return true; }

// Any other type...
template <typename type> bool isString(type arg) { return false; }
```

The examples presented here are not necessarily for detecting strings, but rather to explain the problem of multiple lines of code being dedicated to overloaded functions.

*Imagine if I had to test for a 100+ data types for if they were valid or not, I would quickly want a shorter way of coding this rather than typing all 100 overloaded functions*

Of course, the drawback to this syntactic shorthand is the fact that the data type of `arg` can not then be differentiated (unlike with the standard function overloading).

Comment: For numeric types, there is `std::is_arithmetic`.

Comment: You can use SFINAE idiom in this case. Take look at `std::enable_if`

Comment: If you need to differentiate the actual argument type than collapsing overloads into a template is not something you should do.

Comment: @JesperJuhl - `isNumber(std::vector<std::string>{})`?

Comment: The question is asking if there is a way to collapse multiple overloaded function statements into a single statement. Syntactic sugar basically.

Comment: Why do you need this function at all? You are only testing the type and ignoring the value.

Comment: The question asks: is there a way to collapse multiple overloaded function statements (basically doing similar things) into a more compact form. Assume that I had a 100 overloaded functions detecting if its argument is a string or not, I would prefer not to write those 100 functions syntax-wise.

Comment: My point is that you don't need a *function*. You need a variable template `template<class> bool is_string` and you need to pass it the *type* of the thing you want to check, not the thing itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function is not needed here, because the value of the argument is always ignored. A (const) variable template is enough.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
template <class> const bool is_string = false;
template<> const bool is_string<const char*> = true;
template<> const bool is_string<std::string> = true;

int main() {
   const char* z;
   std::string p;
   int q;

   std::cout << is_string<decltype(z)> << "\n"; 
   std::cout << is_string<decltype(p)> << "\n";
   std::cout << is_string<decltype(q)> << "\n";
}
```

If a function interface is desired, it's trivial to provide

```
 template<class T>
 constexpr bool is_string_f(const T&) {
     return is_string<T>;
 }
```

OK you say, all these specialisations are still too long to write, can we shorten them more? Yes we can.

```
#include <type_traits>
template<class X, class ... args>
const bool type_is_one_of = (false || ... || std::is_same<X, args>::value);
template <class T> 
bool is_string = type_is_one_of<T, char*, const char*, std::string>;
```

[Live example on ideone](https://ideone.com/5xADld).

Answer (score 5):

Probably the best approach would be to start with defining a trait identifying your types:

```
template<typename> struct is_string : std::false_type{};

template<> struct is_string<char*>       : std::true_type{};
template<> struct is_string<char const*> : std::true_type{};
template<> struct is_string<std::string> : std::true_type{};
```

Then you can do all sorts of stuff. For instance, implementing the function in your post becomes this

```
template<typename T> constexpr bool isString(T) { return is_string<T>::value; }
```

Or if you want to control overload resolution, and remove a function from an overload set when the argument isn't a string as we view it:

```
template<typename S>
auto needAString(S s) -> std::enable_if_t<is_string<S>::value>;
```

---

Some pre-defined traits and utilities are already available in the [`<type_traits>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/type_traits) header.

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but I would still like to understand how it has an edge syntactically over plain function overloading.

Comment: @Lapys - You mean what edge putting the relevant information in a table and abstracting the logic has over repeating the same exact logic for different data?

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks.

Comment: @Lapys Providing such info as type instead of as function, allows to use it in compile time evaluation (vs. runtime evaluation). I.e. the compiler can use this info to make type checks or even to compile code conditionally. So, the range of possible usages is larger. Making the functions `constexpr` may move them into the same direction but making such type traits will probably work better in general.

Answer (score 2):

Might

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <string>

template<typename T>
bool is_string(T)
{
    return std::is_constructible<std::string, T>::value;
}
```

be enough?

Answer (score 1):

You might directly do:

```
template <typename T>
constexpr bool isString()
{
    return std::is_same<T, const char*>::value
        || std::is_same<T, char*>::value
        || std::is_same<T, std::string>::value;
}
```

then if you have to set of overloads, you might use SFINAE:

```
template <typename T>
std::enable_if_t<isString<T>()> foo(/**/) { /*..*/}

template <typename T>
std::enable_if_t<!isString<T>()> foo(/**/) { /*..*/}
```

or `if constexpr` (c++17):

```
template <typename T>
void foo(/**/)
{
    if constexpr (isString<T>()) {
        /*..*/
    } else {
        /*..*/
    }
}
```